# Play Framework Forms (Java)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, dependency-injection

I'm checking out the Play! Framework, using Java (don't want to learn a new framework *and* a new language at the same time - I'll incorporate Scala as I learn that), and so far it's awesome.

I'm having a bit of difficulty with forms though. I'm still stuck on the first part [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms) and, as far as I understand, I somehow need to get an instance of `FormFactory` or something related, however I have no idea in which package it might be located, or whether `formFactory` is also another magic method (like `ok`).

Any pointers would be appreciated!

*EDIT* Here's my code:

```
package controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.data.FormFactory;

import play.api.data.Form;
import play.mvc.*;

public class User extends Controller {
    @Inject
    FormFactory form;
    final static Form<model.User> userForm = form(model.User.class);

    public Result post() {
        model.User user = userForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        return ok("The form was received!: " + user);
    }
}
```

The `play.data` package doesn't exit for me. Maybe I did an incorrect install? To be clear, I did start this project from IntelliJ

Comment: Copied from the very page you linked: `To wrap a class you have to inject a play.data.FormFactory into your Controller which then allows you to create the form`

Comment: @Łukasz yeah I saw that; Problem is trying to inject that class throws an exception. Apparently that class doesn't exist. I'll update my question with some more detail.

Comment: For one, I think your form should not be static. According to docs your call should be more like `userForm = form.form(model.User.class)` as `form` is method of `FormFactory`. But about the missing package I don't know. Try creating your project from activator maybe? Maybe you have wrong version of play.

Comment: @Łukasz that seems to have solved the problem - just used activator. Weird. Thanks for your help! Post your comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that your form should not be static as there is no way to initialize it before `FormFactory` is injected.

According to docs this call

```
Form<model.User> userForm = form(model.User.class);
```

should be

```
Form<model.User> userForm = form.form(model.User.class)
```

as `form` is method of `FormFactory`.

If the package is missing from class path its some configuration issue or wrong play version. A working project can be usually obtained through activator.